# Firebase Storage Permissions for Folder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to upload a audio file to my Firebase Storage Bucket.
 There is a folder inside the bucket with the user_id, it should upload the file to this specific folder but the catch is that only that user should be able to access his own folder . 
I looked in to the documentation and set a  rule accordingly, but i seem to be running into a permission issue

```
{  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
```

**My Rule**

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{userId} {
    match /{allPaths=**}{
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    } 
   }
 }
}
```

**Code Snip**

```
String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
final StorageReference audioRef = storageRef.child("/ "+ userUid +"/"+filename());

 //rest of upload task here..
```

The Upload code works perfectly when i set the rule to public access. 
Can someone help me out to figure out whats wrong with the rule i've written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add firebase authentication for this.After that add this permission.
Refer this link [Firebase Security Rules for Cloud Storage Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/)

Came to conclusion that your are missing your Firebase storage bucket name.

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{Pass your firebase storage bucket name here}/o {
  match /{userId} {
    match /{allPaths=**}{
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    } 
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did add Firebase Authentication, and i can see the `userUid` in my firebase console. Where exactly should i add this line of code? @Sachin Soma

Comment: you should add it under rules.

Comment: The rule you mentioned just doesn't seem like the correct type, i get the following error. Error saving rules - Line 1: mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'service', 'rules_version'} @Sachin Soma

Comment: you need to edit these according to your database structure.audio_node_name is the node you want to add permission for.

Comment: I do not have a database with my firebase. I simply want to store the files at storage level.